# How to play measures 5 through 7 of Mozart's Turkish March

Tags: piano, keyboard, performance-practice

How do you play this highlighted part from Turkish March on the keyboard?
[image: Mozart, K311, third movement, measures 5–7]
Press GAB together?
Or 1 after the other with GA quickly? It sounded weird after the first bar that way.

Do I press E that is highlighted (bass clef) beginning from the main note (B) or do I press it when beginning to play G in the “superscript” note? (When googling I figured out these are called Grace notes but I am still a bit unsure how to do it in this piece).

Comment: With so much now available to watch and listen to on you tube in particular, it's always worth spending a little time finding any piece in question, and checking out how others play it. So much instant gratification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The G and A are **grace notes**. In this piece they should be played separately and quickly, before the beat, leading to the B, which occurs on the beat.

The left-hand E should occur on the beat at the same time as the right-hand B.

The passage can be heard played in this way in the below Lang Lang recording. Notice that he plays them so quickly that they sound nearly simultaneous.

Daniel Barenboim plays it similarly.

As does Maria João Pires.

Comment: Good on you for the example videos of famous performances of the piece, that's usually a good quick sanity check on interpretation questions like this one.